# To get status that dependent on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

| p_da | q_ | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 |  |
| b | 5 |  |
| b | 4 |  |
| a | 3 |  |
| a | 8 |  |
| b | 7 |  |
| b | 6 |  |
| c | 4 |  |
| b | 4 |  |

Output should be:

| p_da | q_ | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | old |
| b | 5 | old |
| b | 4 | old |
| a | 3 | old |
| a | 8 | New |
| b | 7 | New |
| b | 6 | old |
| c | 4 | New |
| b | 4 | old |

R is depends on P_da and q_, first we check p:

- a=5 - old
- a=3 - old
- a=8 greatest so new.

How do I get R?

Comment: What about for `b` and `c`? How do you make the rules?

Comment: is New when it is greater than the last old or when it is the max of its group?

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `groupby` with `transform`, then `np.where`

```
s = df.groupby('p_da')['q_'].transform('max')
df['R'] = np.where(df['q_'].eq(s), 'New', 'Old')
```